Table Adapter vs SqlPipe (special case)
I have a SQL Server Server1 with a database database1 which is not normalized; this makes it harder to use for different purposes like external clients (tools for visualization, other programs, etc..) and cannot be modified (for many reasons).
To be able to use other clients efficiently, I have another SQL Server Server2 where the databases are optimized and data from Server1 is modified and inserted into Server2.
As an example from Server1.database1.dbo.TableA inserts its data into both Server2.database2.dbo.TableB and Server2.database2.dbo.TableC. This can be done via T-SQL (triggers, procedures, etc).
But in some situations it is more convenient to develop a DLL and register the assembly in SQL Server and fire the trigger on UPDATE.
I attempted to develop a DLL and to register the assembly on Server2 that will fire on UPDATE on Server2 for Table_ActNow.
I developed the class using C# and .NET 4.8. The logic of my class was to use table adapters that will load the data from Server1.TableA with an SQL command like SELECT TOP(1) * FROM TableA ORDER BY Date DESC into a data set via the Fill() method, process the loaded data, populate two other data sets with processed data and use those 2 objects to insert into Server2.TableB and Server2.TableC via table adapter of each dataset using INSERT.
The problem is if my class is fired by SQL Server, Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MSDTC) which manages transactions and connections and in this case will report errors (DTC is configured correct on both servers, and work properly).
After days of debugging I figure out that the SQL command methods of the table adapter are not exposed, in conclusion the transaction will fail.
The only workaround that could work is to add in partial class of the table adapter methods that will expose further the SQL command methods (I did not test this !)
According to Microsoft documentation, table adapters should be used in CRUD applications.
Also from the Microsoft documentation regarding transactions, they give examples of using SqlPipe, in this case I have to manage opening and closing connections and verify if the SqlCommand fulfill the job during the transaction.
Because I observed when using table adapters to fill the dataset and then do something with this data, the process is much faster and more efficient compared wit the other case where I have to manage the connection, create variables, and prepare other steps to work with the data, as is the case when I use SqlPipe.
From the point of view of an experienced person I would like to know what is the elegant end optimized way to do it (in .NET)?
It is wrong to use further table adapters or is too much effort?
Should I go with SqlPipe?

I think you should check out bulk insert which should be fast, SQLPipe probably pipes out the stuff back to the client which you don't want? Bulk should be able to accept your dataset or whatever and use it to import into the target server

Honestly, this sounds like a job for an ETL process managed by Integration Services (SSIS) rather than a custom dll. But if you really want to use .Net, I wouldn't bother with custom classes. I'd write the raw SQL for the INSERT statements and populate the SqlParameters directly from the DataSet received from Server1. I'd also never use TOP 1 without a matching ORDER BY

Thank you for remarks @JoelCoehoorn
For SQL query you are right it is ORDER BY Date desc  (the descripton started to be already very long, I was in a hurry) ,I will edit.
Regarding the writing RAW SQL for INSERT most of the time I do but for this table became too much SQL and should perform alot of string operations and reorganization (I understand that the engine can do it but is too much "SQLOLOGY" for me to do this). Which is more simple for me to achieve using .NET and C#.

I took a look at SSIS, and I found in Microsoft documentation the Custom Task topic link.
It's not clear to me how different it is from what I'm already trying.
